# How to create a new column in Apache Solr during full import?

Tags: mysql, database, solr

This is the current query I am using for my Apache Solr full import.

```
<document>
       <entity name="id" query="select f_name as 'id', f_name, l_name, AES_DECRYPT(l_name,'key')as decp_col from table_name;"/>

</document>
```

This is the format I get on Apache Solr.

```
l_name":["4\u0007{¾Nen•øÕ+·$Õ\u0002"],
        "f_name":["Jayde"],
        "id":"Jayde",
        "_version_":1650635178055303168},
```

I want it to be imported in a way that I get a decp_col with the decrypted values.

I have tried multiple queries but am unable to generate anything on Sokr side.

Comment: Seems like the decryption is failing and giving random binary data? Do your query work as it should when issued in a regular MySQL console?

Comment: The query works, so does the decryption during normal execution. I just want to create a new column with these decrypted values.

Comment: In that case it should be enough to add a corresponding `field` element in your XML in the same was as for the other fields. If you have no `field` elements, it should be included by default as long as you have a `decp_col` defined in your schema.

Comment: Could you please help with the field element on the db_config file. Or what changes are required in the schema.
The changes I made are not working.

Comment: What changes did you make to the schema? Did you reload the schema afterwards? Are you using the managed schema? Does the new field show in the administration interface for your Solr node?

Comment: Based on your suggestion, i found this:
<field name="_NAME_" column="_COL_NAME"/>